# Jest - TypeError: _axios.default.create is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I want to check if email field is present in Login page in reactjs. And I'm getting error as
TypeError: _axios.default.create is not a function

But if I want to check the email field is present in the login form or not, why I need to call the login api? I am new in testing, so I can miss something.

Login.test.js

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Login from "./Login";

// jest.mock("axios");

test('Enter valid email', () => {
render(<Login />)
const emailElement = screen.getByLabelText('Enter Email')
expect(emailElement).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

Login.jsx

```
import {axiosPublic} from '../../api/apiMethod'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Login.scss'
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { loginWithGoogle } from '../../features/auth/authSlice';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

const Login = () => {
const {
register,
handleSubmit,
watch,
formState: {errors}
} = useForm({
defaultValues: {
email: ""
}
});
const email = watch('email')

const navigate = useNavigate()
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const {isSuccess} = useSelector(state => state.auth)
const [error, setError] = useState('')
const [status, setStatus] = useState(null)
const [openInstructions, setOpenInstructions] = useState(false)

const loginHandler = async () => {
try {
const res = await axiosPublic.post('/auth/login', {email})
setStatus(res?.status)
} catch (error) {
setError(error?.response?.data?.message)
setTimeout(() => {
setError('')  
}, 2000);
}
}

useEffect(() => {
const sendOtp = async () => {
const res = await axiosPublic.post(`/auth/sendotp/${email}`)
console.log(res.data)

      if(res.data?.otp){
        navigate(`/loginOTP/${email}`, {state: res?.data?.otp})
      }
    }
    
    
    status === 200 && sendOtp()

}, [navigate, status, email])

const googleLoginHandler = async (credentialResponse) => {
console.log(credentialResponse)
await dispatch(loginWithGoogle({userToken: credentialResponse.credential}))
}

return (
<>
      <section className="form-container">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(loginHandler)} className="form">
          <div className="input-field">
            <label>Enter Email</label>
            <input type="email"
              {...register("email", { 
                required: "Email is required"
                })} 
              />
            <p className='input-error'>{errors.email?.message}</p>
            {error && <p className="input-error">{error}</p>}
          </div>

          <input type="submit" value="Continue" className="button-cart" />
          <p>
            Not registered yet? &nbsp;
            <Link to='/signup'>Sign up</Link>
          </p>

          <div className='divider'>
            <hr />
            <p>OR</p>
          </div>
          
          <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <GoogleLogin
              onSuccess={googleLoginHandler}
              onError={() => {
                  toast.error('Login Failed');
              }}
              render={(renderProps) => (
                <button
                  className="custom-google-login-button"
                  onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                  disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                >
                  Sign in with Google
                </button>
              )}
              buttonText="Login"
            />
          </div>
        </form>

      </section>
    </>
)
}

export default Login
```

apiMethod.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export const axiosPublic = axios.create({
baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
headers: {
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '\*'
},
withCredentials: true
})
```

Package.json

```
{
"name": "client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
"@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
"@mui/material": "^5.11.15",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.0.4",
"@react-oauth/google": "^0.7.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.32.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
"axios": "^1.3.2",
"firebase": "^9.17.1",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-accessible-accordion": "^5.0.0",
"react-countdown": "^2.3.5",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.42.1",
"react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
"react-icons": "^4.7.1",
"react-modal": "^3.16.1",
"react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
"react-rating": "^2.0.5",
"react-redux": "^8.0.5",
"react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
"react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"react-slick": "^0.29.0",
"react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
"react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"sass": "^1.57.1",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"sweetalert2": "^11.7.13",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
"yup": "^0.32.11"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns "node_modules/(?!axios)/" --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": \[
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
\]
},
"browserslist": {
"production": \[
"\>0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
\],
"development": \[
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
\]
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
"babel-jest": "^29.6.2",
"jest": "^27.5.1"
}
}
```

I tried to install @babel/core, babel-jest, nothing helped